# The lightest JavaFX container for Polygon

Tags: java, javafx

Due to the lack of easily accessible and readable libraries or methods for two-dimensional contour plotting in Java 8 environment, I decided to write such functionality myself. My solution is based on the approach described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marching_squares#Isoband) and it can be summed up as follows:

I create a rectangular container with specific `layoutX` and `layoutY` describing its position on the contour map. I draw in this container appropriate polygon depends on the ternary index assigned to the aforementioned container.

Taking into account, that each container is created for four data values from given dataset, it is easy to calculate, that for matrix with size of [11,11] there will be 10^2 containers, but for matrix with size of [1001, 1001] it will be 10^6.

In this case, it is necessary to choose appropriate container for polygon, in order to optimize plotting for larger datasets as much as it is possible.

Which container should I choose in order to provide best execution times for the creation of contour map based on the assumptions described above?

Answer (score 0):

The lites container is probably a Group or no container at all if you just apply the appropriate transform to your Polygon. But I don't understand why you are actually looking for this. The algorithm that you linked to is for computing iso-lines but is not efficient to use the same setup to display the result of this computation.

Comment: Do you know something efficient for displaying result of this computation?

Comment: As I understand it, the result of all your computations should just be a set of polygons which you could display directly without any special containers or such.

Comment: Ah, ok. I will use `javafx.scene.layout.StackPane` for the first implementation. Maybe I'll give up it in the later stages of the function development.